# Please Explain me print(True>False) and print(False>True)

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I wrote a code

```
print(False>True)
print(True>False)
```

result are

```
False
True
```

can someone explain me what is this happening

Comment: `print(int(True))`  -  `print(int(False))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, when you use booleans in a greater/lower than comparison they are automatically considered as numbers, so `True` becomes `1` and `False` becomes `0`. Replace them and the answer becomes obvious:

```
print(0 > 1)
print(1 > 0)
```

The first check is `False` and the second check is `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean values are also integers and have an integer value:

```
>>> type(False)
<class 'bool'>
>>> bool.mro()  # base classes include integer
[<class 'bool'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'object'>]
>>> int(False)
0
>>> int(True)
1
```

So False(0) is *not* greater than True(1), and True(1) *is* greater than False(0).

Answer (score 0):

You're basically printing whether or not 0 (False) is greater than 1 (True), which is False, and then vice versa for the second statement

Answer (score 0):

> Boolean result always return 0 or False for false and 1 or True for true

From : [Py Doc](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html)

For more clarity :

```
>>> False
False
>>> False>True
False
>>> 0>1
False
>>> True>False
True
>>> 1>0
True
```